# How to correctly bind TextBox Text property for attached behavior?

Tags: regex, wpf, xaml

In studying the classic article by Josh Smith, [Regex Validation in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15610/Regex-Validation-in-WPF),
I am having an error (VS 2010) of:

> *Error    134 The TextBox's Text property must be bound for the RegexValidator to validate it.*

This is thrown at

```
  <TextBox 
  Text="{Binding Path=DateString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
  jas:RegexValidator.RegexText="{x:Static local:DateFormatRegex.DateRegex}" 
  jas:RegexValidator.ErrorMessage="Invalid date format." 
  />
```

It appears to me that *the text is bound*. What's wrong? (I have no clue :( ).

Any help is most appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Perhaps, you will find some clues in [Data validation in WPF](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/)...

Comment: @stribizhev Excellent article, but does not address the issue with an attached behavior :(  Thanks.

Comment: Are there any binding errors in the output console? Maybe it could not resolve your binding expression.

Comment: @GlenThomas The error shows up when the xaml is opened--but compilation reports no errors. (The xaml has blue lines underlining the <TextBox> with the above error. Output window shows no errors.) :(

Comment: The error "The TextBox's Text property must be bound for the RegexValidator to validate it." is a runtime error. This would not cause compilation to fail.

Comment: So you see the error without running the application? That would probably be because you have not set the DataContext at design time. Does it work ok when you run the application?

Comment: @GlenThomas  Yes!  Just tried it. It runs perfectly--even though the error still shows when viewing the xaml.. ???

Comment: @GlenThomas How can the DataContext be set at design time to avoid these errors? Thanks.

Comment: First you need to create an instance of the viewmodel and second you need to set it as the DataContext. I will provide some code in an answer

Comment: @GlenThomas An instance can be created at design time??? Interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the error because you have not set a design-time DataContext for the XAML designer to work with.

You could do this in the XAML. Add this to the UserControl/Window attributes:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProjectName.ViewModels"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

(Replace your project name, ViewModel name, etc.)

If your ViewModel does not have a parameterless constructor, you can create an instance from the code-behind of the view, e.g.:

```
public MyControl()
{
    DataContext = new MyViewModel("a parameter");
}
```

Obviously this has its limitations as the application is not executing.

Comment: Thanks. I believe that is the answer. Unfortunately, my viewmodel contstructor requires serveral parameters used to connect to a backend database so does not have a parameterless constructor. needed by the xaml. Can parameters be passed into this instance from the XAML? :)

Comment: You might have some success with creating an instance from the constructor of the code-behind class, but there is only so much you can do at design time! If it is important to you, then you could create a base class for your viewmodel that does have a parameterless constructor and contains the properties for binding and use that for your design-time requirements.

Comment: If the error is ignorable at design time, I can live with that. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes you can simply ignore it.